# show null attributes json response spring data rest?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-data-rest

Imagine I have an entity like this.

```
public class Person{
  Long Id,
  String name,
  String city,
  Long age

  //getters, setters, constructor
}
```

When I create a repository and output using GET request for an entry for city is null, below is my json response.

```
{
  "name": "jon",
  "age": 34
}
```

But I want this instead.

```
{
  "name": "jon",
  "city": null,
  "age": 34
}
```

i.e. showing null attributes.

What is the easiest work around?

Comment: this is strange. Anyway you should be able in configuring the ObjectMapper by properly setting the serializationInclusion property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should check to json annotation JsonInclude.Include and set it to ALWAYS :
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that you *don't have* the following configuration in your `ObjectMapper`:

```java
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

If you have it, remove it or change to [`Include.ALWAYS`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#ALWAYS).

---

Also check your `application.properties`. If you're using Spring Boot 1.3, the serialization inclusion is configured via the `spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion` property.

Jackson 2.7 and Spring Boot 1.4 uses a property named `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion`.

Ensure that the value of such properties is `non_null`.

---

Alternativaly, annotate your class as follows:

```java
@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)
public class Person {
    ...
}
```