# Cannot show null object in jsonobject

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have called a rest api from exsternal system using restTemplate. everything is work fine but when I get null in some of values (in example the footer value is null) it is always give jsonexception error

result api

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "id": "22",
        "organization_id": "33",
        "name": "name_isf",
        "language": "id",
        "header": {
            "format": "IMAGE",
            "example": "#<Hashie::Mash header_handle=#<Hashie::Array [\"result_pic"]>>"
        },
        "body": "contenty for body",
        "footer": null,
        "buttons": [],
        "status": "APPROVED",
        "category": "PERSONAL_FINANCE_UPDATE"
    }
}
```

every call api exsternal i always catch with jsonobject like below

```
JSONObject res2 = qontakService.getDetailTemplate();
```

then i will give that to the controller

```
JSONObject gabunganResult = new JSONObject();
gabunganResult.put("template", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(getDetail.get()));
gabunganResult.put("templateQontak", res2);
```

and the result error is

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Object is null (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["details"]->net.sf.json.JSONObject["templateQontak"]->net.sf.json.JSONObject["data"]->net.sf.json.JSONObject["footer"]->net.sf.json.JSONNull["empty"])
```

how do I solve this problem ? thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421295/show-null-attributes-json-response-spring-data-rest

Comment: it is in a class, whereas what I need is in the form of a jsonobject. I have tried it and still cant work

Comment: Can you give sample code to reproduce this issue?